# How to animate a router-view view changes in Aurelia?

Tags: css-animations, aurelia

I'm new to animating in Aurelia and having trouble getting it working on a simple route.  Here's what I am trying:

**app.html**

```
<template>
    <div style="display:flex; flex-direction: row;flex-grow:1">
       <span style="display:flex" repeat.for="route of router.navigation">
          <a href.bind="route.href">${route.title}</a>
       </span>
    </div>
    <router-view swap-order="with" style="height:300px"></router-view>
</template>
```

**app.js**

```
import {CssAnimator} from 'aurelia-animate-css'

export class App {
  static inject = ["CssAnimator"]
  configureRouter(config,router){
     config.title = "TestApp"
     config.map([
        {route: ['','page1'], name: 'page1', moduleId: './page1', nav: true, title: "Page1"},
        {route: "page2", name: "page2", moduleId: './page2', nav: true, title: "Page2"}
     ]);

   this.router = router;
}
```

**style.css**

```
@keyframes slideLeftIn {
    0% { transform: translate(100%,0)}
    100% { transform: none; }
}

@keyframes slideLeftOut {
    0% { transform: none; }
    100% {transform: translate(-100%, 0); }
}

.viewedit{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    height: 300px;
}
.viewedit.au-enter-active {
    animation: slideLeftIn 0.8s;
}
.viewedit.au-leave-active {
    animation: slideLeftOut 0.8s;
}
```

**Page1.html**

```
<template>
    <div class="viewedit au-animate">
       <h1>Page 1</h1>
    </div>
</template>
```

My view changes as I click the link, but the views don't slide in and out -- they just act like any other non-animated navigation.

**Update**

Based on Ashley's response, I have made a few changes like so:

**main.js**

```
import 'aurelia-animator-css';  //removed this line as well

export async function configure(aurelia){
   aurelia.use
      .standardConfiguration()
      .developmentLogging()
      .plugin("aurelia-animator-css");
   ...
}
```

**app.js**

```
//removed import and static inject of CssAnimator
```

**package.json**

```
...
},
"dependencies": {
    "aurelia-animator-css":"^1.0.2",  //this line was added
    ...
}
```

However, now when I try to run the app, I get an error message in the console window: `Unable to find module with ID: aurelia-animator-css` and my app never gets past the "loading" screen.

**Update 2**

Because I was using the Webpack Skeleton project from Aurelia, I had to add the plugin like so:

```
.plugin(PLATFORM.moduleName('aurelia-animator-css'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install the animator as a plugin. Then, the `au-animate` class will work as you expect. You install plugins in your `main.js` file. It will look something like this:

```
export function configure(aurelia) {
  aurelia.use
    .standardConfiguration()
    .feature('resources')
    .plugin('aurelia-animator-css');

  aurelia.start().then(() => aurelia.setRoot());
}
```

Note that you'll need to install the `aurelia-animator-css` plugin using your package manager (NPM or JSPM). Note that it is `aurelia-animatOR-css`, not `aurelia-animatE-css`.

This line isn't necessary in `app.js`, so you can remove it:

```
 static inject = ["CssAnimator"];
```

Once you do this, everything should start working as you expect.

Comment: Thanks.  However, I'm getting an error when I run my code now during bootstrapping `Unable to find module with ID: aurelia-animator-css`.  My package.json file does include a dependency for `"aurelia-animator-css" : "^1.0.2"`  I'll add an update to my post to show my current code.

Comment: Got it!  I was using the skeleton project for Webpack.  They actually had a line in there to uncomment in order to add animation that I had missed before.  Basically, exactly what you had bu they added `PLATFORM.moduleName('aurelia-animator-css')`  Not sure what that's all about but it does get things working.

Comment: The `PLATFORM.moduleName` stuff is needed to allow Webpack to do static analysis, I believe. I've had it explained to me repeatedly, and I'm not really a fan of it, but it is what it is.